# NotFoundHttpException when updating,selecting,posting using my restful api

Tags: laravel, rest

I have problem on my api when i try to access my api using the get request, on my postman it says that **"message": "The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST.",** I am currently using laravel for creating a restful api. this is the part of weirds thing happen. on my localhost the api is working fine and the data is showing. however on my staging it gives error that **The GET method is not supported for this route.**

Here is the error on my postman:

[image: Error]

**My API:**

```
Route::get('assured','AssuredController@index');
```

Controller:

```
public function index()
{
    // Get List Assured
    $Assureds = Assured::all();

    return AssuredResource::collection($Assureds);
    
}
```

Route list:

[image: Route List]

Api.php

[image: api]

Comment: Could you please use `php artisan route:list` to view all routes on your staging server? Your output should be updated in your post.

Comment: sure. will do it thanks

Comment: @ThânLƯƠNG please see the new update

Comment: @ThânLƯƠNG the weird here is the other api is working like /api/region well okay, however on that api/assured that only api is not working

Comment: I see that you have two times with `api/assured`. Did you define two times in your route? Could you please share more lines of code in your `route.php`?

Comment: @ThânLƯƠNG sure

Comment: When you use `php artisan route:clear` on staging server, did you have the same error?

Comment: yes all things i do, php artisan route:clear, php artisan config:clear, php artisan cache:clear, php artisan view:clear

Comment: On localhost, do the five routes with `api/assured` work fine?

Comment: yes it works properly and other api is working well

Comment: What happens when you drop the slash at the end of the URL?

Comment: @DevGe With your routes, you only get the error on staging error. I think you should see again server config. Maybe, you made a redirect by default, so you lost GET parameters in the way. Could you please share your config server?

Comment: @MaartenVeerman same error